# Building a Custom RNG

Tags: javascript, function

I am building an app for people who like to play the lottery.  The app will take in data from the user such as birthdays, street addresses, license plates, lucky numbers, times, etc.  The user will fill their number diary with whatever they want.  I will concatenate these strings of numbers into a solo string for each user.

I then will run the following function to get the frequency of each digit 0 - 9 as it appears in the string.

```
var digitFreq= function(numString){
    zeros = numString.split("0").length-1
    ones = numString.split("1").length-1
    twos = numString.split("2").length-1
    threes = numString.split("3").length-1
    fours = numString.split("4").length-1
    fives = numString.split("5").length-1
    sixes = numString.split("6").length-1
    sevens = numString.split("7").length-1
    eights = numString.split("8").length-1
    nines = numString.split("9").length-1
    numbers = numString.length;
    zeroPrcnt = zeros/numbers    
    onePrcnt = ones/numbers     
    twoPrcnt = twos/numbers     
    threePrcnt = threes/numbers     
    fourPrcnt = fours/numbers     
    fivePrcnt = fives/numbers     
    sixPrcnt = sixes/numbers     
    sevPrcnt = sevens/numbers     
    eightPrcnt = eights/numbers     
    ninePrcnt = nines/numbers
}
```

This will return the frequency % of each digit in the number string.  My question is how do I take these frequencies and dynamically build an RNG that uses each user's personal frequency percentages when drawing a three digit, four digit, or mega lottery number?

The user will use their RNG to generate lottery numbers to play.

Comment: how does this code even work in the first place, what did `zeros/numbers` and the rest division operator gave to you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just concatenate all entries in one string and then randomly choose a character from that string. Each number would have a probability related to the number of times it appears in the string.

Comment: How about generating a double digit number?  Like 27 or 64 where you put two random number draws together?